# Using the value of a MongoDB field to update another field

Tags: mongodb, monk

I have a MongoDB document with a structure like this:

```
{
    testValue: 10,
    maxValue: 20
}
```

I want to set `testValue` to an arbitrary integer value between 0 and `maxValue`. Ideally, I would do something like this:

```
db.collection.update(
    {},
    {
        $set: { 'testValue': newValue },
        $min: { 'testValue': 0 },
        $max: { 'textValue': $maxValue }
    }
)
```

But that obviously doesn't work. There are a handful of threads that relate to this question (e.g. [Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)), but they're all a few years old, and I can't find pertinent information in the official documentation. Is there a way to do what I want, or do I have to use find() to get `maxValue` then do a separate call to the database using update()?

Comment: It is still not possible, will try to dig out the JIRA ticket for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still not possible in Mongo 3.2 or lower, check for example these JIRA tickets:

1. [Self referential updates](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1765)
2. [Allow update to compute expressions using referenced fields](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11345)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed to know.